# Div "jumping" over page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I made chat, and I am using ajax to refresh messages

```
function loadlink(){
    $('#porukice').load('messages.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 2000);
```

The div

```
<div  id="porukice" style=""></div>
```

Is moving over a page three times, then it stops but in odd place.
The first time element appear on page everything is fine, but after 2 ajax reloads it change place and stops, ajax still works.
I really can't figure out why is this happening.

[image]

[image]

That is how it moves with ajax reload.

Comment: You `unwrap()` every time, so every time you remove a new parent element, which is probably not at all what you want ?

Comment: I just want message.php to reload so it can show new messages. Do you know any better way to do this? How facebook does it. EDIT: even when i remove unwrap it is jumping, i never seen this in my life, this is so awkward. Why does div changes position 3 times? And them stops in position as seen on last image? Is Bootstrap problem? o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You guys wont believe what was problem.
I just realized that because text input box had `size="150"`set, div element above jumped like insane. It's fixed now.